# How can show the following function has a global maximum?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I want to show that
$$f(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_m)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i^{b_i}}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i)^{\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}b_i}\prod_{j=1}^{2}[\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_ic_i+d_j]^{a_j}}~~\alpha_i, b_i, c_i, d_j, a_j>0$$
has a global maximum. How can I do it?